# Why will this hailstone number producer not work?

Tags: java, jpanel, actionlistener

I am trying to make a JButton on a JPanel that, when clicked, produces the hailstone number (if the number is even divide by two; if the number is odd, multiply by 3 and then add one). However, when I click my JButton, the program freezes and no number is outputted. Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Panel03 extends JPanel {
private JLabel label;
private JButton button;
private JTextField box;

public Panel03()
{
    box = new JTextField("0", 10);
    box.setForeground(Color.black);
    box.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    add(box);
    
    label = new JLabel();
    label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
    label.setForeground(Color.blue);
    add(label);

    button = new JButton("Next");
    button.addActionListener(new Listener());
    add(button);
}

private class Listener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String s = box.getText();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(s);
        int b = a;
        do {
            if(a%2 == 0){b/=2.0;}
            else{a=((3*b)+1);}
            label.setText(Integer.toString(b));
        }
        while(b!= 4||b!= 2||b!= 1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Every existing number is either not 4 or not 2. Maybe you meant `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: You are not using `a` after setting the value inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a program freezes, a infinite loop is a prime suspect. In this case, adding this line to the loop

```
  System.out.printf("* a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
```

shows that a=0 and b=0 forever. Since a is zero, a%2=0, and b/=2 is still zero, so the variables never change. Starting with a=1 still gets stuck at a=4, b=0. In fact for any number I entered, b goes to zero and the loop gets stuck. I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but I suspect your loop exit logic should be and instead of or, and needs to catch the b=0 possibility:

```
  while (b!=4 && b!=2 && b!=1 && b!=0);
```